# Solr cursor behavior

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrcloud

My understanding on solr cursor was that it is used as an alternative of setting start values while executing solr query. But, I happened to notice some solr queries, which has cursors and also having start,rows,offset and limit configured. Can someone please help me to understand how does the solr behave in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the reference guide about cursorMarks](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/pagination-of-results.html):

> cursorMark and start are mutually exclusive parameters.
>
> Your requests must either not include a start parameter, or it must be specified with a value of “0”.

`rows` still has meaning, since it's how many rows that should be returned from Solr (from the cursorMark).

Solr has no arguments named `offset` or `limit` that are used in their default query handlers.

Comment: Thanks Matslindh. If we have defined both start and cursor for a query, will solr give precedence to cursor?

Comment: If you give a `start` value that is different from `0`, the request will be denied with a generated exception. https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/c99af207c761ec34812ef1cc3054eb2804b7448b/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/CursorMark.java#L86

Comment: Looking at the code it seems like even if we are using cursor, we need to provide the start parameter with the value 0 only then the cursor will start working.Is that correct?

Comment: You do not need to provide a value, since it's 0 by default - but _if_ you provide a value, it has to be 0. https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/c99af207c761ec34812ef1cc3054eb2804b7448b/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/SortSpec.java#L31